# Adding filter in django OrderingFilter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

Is there a way to add a filter to queryset for a specific ordering field like "created" in OrderingFilter?
I want to have this filter for ordering:

```
F('created').desc(nulls_last=True)
```

Here is my code:

```
class ProductFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    ordering = filters.OrderingFilter(fields=['price', 'created'])

    class Meta:
        model = Product
```

Comment: In `class Meta` you must to have `fields` property and pass all fields that you want to filter . There you can define extra fields too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
class NullsLastOrderingFilter(filters.OrderingFilter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value in ([], (), {}, '', None):
            return qs

        ordering = [self.get_ordering_value(param) for param in value]

        def filter_object(x):
            return F(x[1:]).desc(
                nulls_last=True
            ) if x[0] == '-' else F(x).asc(
                nulls_last=True
            )

        if ordering:
            ordering = map(filter_object, ordering)
            queryset = qs.order_by(*ordering)

        return queryset


class ProductFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    ordering = NullsLastOrderingFilter(fields=['price', 'created'])

    class Meta:
        model = Product
```